# Limited number of video uploads

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We get error "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload" after uploading 10 videos each day
We have multiple Youtube channels - but only 1 of them getting this limitation of 10 videos per day
How can we fix this? Is it something in the settings?

We tried to look for a solution in Stackoverflow but we couldn't find any official answer

Comment: Instead of looking in StackOverflow, consider Checking Youtube.

Comment: Check on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc)